# Tie multiple checkboxes to multiple listbox properties

Tags: c#, checkbox, listbox

I have 30 listboxes and 30 checkboxes. I want each checkbox to control each listbox.enabled property. For now, I my best idea is to create 30 different methods, one for each pair of checkbox1 - listbox1, checkbox2 - listbox2 etc, but I don't think this scales very well if I need to add more pairs in the future.

Is there an easier way to do this? I thought of a foreach-loop that goes through every checkbox in the Form but then how do I make that loop understand that if it's dealing with checkbox15 it should change the .enabled of listbox15?
I'm pretty new at this so I appreciate different suggestions :)

As of now, I have 30 of these: (with the rest of them changed to checkBox2/listBox2 etc)

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            if (listBox1.Items.Count >= 1)
            {
                tillgangligaForare.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[0]);
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                uppdateraSummering();
            }

            listBox1.Enabled = false;
            listBox1.Items.Add("FORDON EJ I BRUK");
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Enabled = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Use bindings to bind the Checked property of the checkbox to the Enabled property of the listbox.  You'll still have to write some tedious code to do that, but you won't need 30 click handlers.

Comment: are you familiar with the `Controls` class and how you can do a `ForEach(Control ctrl in Controls)` the you can check if `ctrl` if CheckBox` from there check if it's state is checked or not etc.. no need to write 30 different methods..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the two suggestions by Lotharyx and Sasway Padhan, with the Load() event of the Form, giving:

```
    private Dictionary<CheckBox, ListBox> lookup = new Dictionary<CheckBox, ListBox>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lb;
        CheckBox cb;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
        {
            lb = this.Controls.Find("listBox" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as ListBox;
            cb = this.Controls.Find("checkBox" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;
            if (lb != null && cb != null)
            {
                lookup.Add(cb, lb);

            }
        }
    }

    private void checkBoxes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
        if (lookup.ContainsKey(cb))
        {
            ListBox lb = lookup[cb];

            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                if (lb.Items.Count >= 1)
                {
                    tillgangligaForare.Items.Add(lb.Items[0]);
                    lb.Items.Clear();
                    uppdateraSummering();
                }

                lb.Enabled = false;
                lb.Items.Add("FORDON EJ I BRUK");
            }
            else
            {
                lb.Items.Clear();
                lb.Enabled = true;
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! One single click-handler and it's easy to add more controls and just add to the for-loop. I've also learned about Dictionary, in which I will dig deeper to learn more about. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple possible approaches:

- Use Bindings to bind the Enabled property on the listbox to the Checked property on its checkbox.  You'll still have to write code to create all the bindings (there may be a way to do this in the visual designer)
- Make a Dictionary of checkboxes to listboxes, and create a single click handler (which you will give to each checkbox) which will use the "sender" argument to look up the correct listbox to enable/disable from the dictionary.

Both of these involve code you'll have to remember to update when you add another pair of controls, but both should only require one or two new lines for each new pair.

Answer (score 1):

Find the checkbox name from sender argument. The use following to find the listbox control matching the number suffix:

```
int suffix = 1; // Get from Checkbox name suffix
ListBox tbx = this.Controls.Find("listbox" + suffix, true).FirstOrDefault() as ListBox;
tbx.Enabled = false;
```